# Live tile inside windows phone 7 application

Tags: windows-phone-7, live-tile

Is it possible to create a live tile inside our windows phone 7 application? I am asking the similar functionality as in AppHub app "...i'm a WP7!".

Please provide me input, how i can achieve this functionality?

Comment: What have you tried? Where have you looked? It feels like your asking us to write your app.

Comment: Dear ChristiaanV, I'm asking, How can i achieve this kind of functionality? Any pointer to this direction will be helpful. It is hardly a week, i've started with this new platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the HubTile control from the Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone over at [codeplex](http://silverlight.codeplex.com).

Just be careful that it looks good and makes sense in your app - it's a very dynamic control and you can't see the Title of the control all the time.